# ERROR - Must Declare Scalar Variable - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, variables, scalar

I am doing a function for uploading files into folder using C#. It occur and error where the error is "Must declare the scalar variable "@TABLE_ID" after I click upload. I have done some research and try to use others example but the error still occurs. This is the function for upload:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ulysses"].ConnectionString;
        string filenam = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        string TABLE_NAME = "REQUEST";

        int table_id = -1;
        table_id = generateNextId("SP_LINK_TABLE_FIELD_ID");

        string path = @"C:\Users\muhd\Documents\CyberLink";

        path = path + filenam;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "Insert into OLE(LINK_TABLE_ID, LINK_TABLE_NAME, OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME) values(@TABLE_ID,@TABLE_NAME,@FILE_NAME)";
       cmd.CommandType =  CommandType.Text;
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = table_id;
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_NAME", TABLE_NAME);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE_NAME",path);
       cmd.Connection = con;
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
    }
```

the table_id is taken from a stored procedure using another function. Please refer below:

```
protected int generateNextId(string strStoredProcedureName)//this is for inserting table_field_id for uploading attachment
    {
        int intNewId = 0;
        try
        {
            strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ulysses"].ToString();
            conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            command = new SqlCommand(strStoredProcedureName, conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@newid", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@newid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            intNewId = (int)command.Parameters["@newid"].Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn = null;
        }
        return intNewId;
    }
   }
```

This is the stored procedure that I use:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LINK_TABLE_FIELD_ID]
AS
begin tran;
declare @nextid integer;
update generator set current_number = current_number + 1 where generator = 'LINK_TABLE_FIELD';
select @nextid = current_number from generator where generator = 'LINK_TABLE_FIELD';
commit tran;
return @nextid;
```

I am not sure why it needed to be declare even other function with the same style has no problem with the code but this one shows this error. I hope anyone can give some insight about this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're setting the query to the variable `cmd` but then want to assign the parameters to the variable `command`. Something there doesn't just match up.

Comment: Please try change command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = table_id; to - ommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_ID",table_id);

Comment: This is not `mysql`, but SQL Server. And please, use proper means of generating unique IDs. Your code is not safe to race conditions. Instead, use the `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're executing is `cmd` and not `command`.You're not adding the parameters to the correct command object.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = table_id;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_NAME", TABLE_NAME);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE_NAME",path);
```

should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = table_id;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TABLE_NAME", TABLE_NAME);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILE_NAME",path);
```

Comment: @DenisWessels He may be adding the parameters to another global object. This way, SQL treats `@TABLE_ID` as a scalar query variable that is not found. `SqlCommand` doesn't replace it with the value then. It is a variable name issue in his case.